# google sheets - how to retrieve column based on first occurence of an X?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a timeline-like sheet, where I mark activities using x, where the first column is an activity, and the following columns are week numbers.

How can I achieve something along with the screenshot?

[image]

This is to create a list of certain activities, and showing which week they start. As you can see, the week number is selected from each column for each activity, based on the first x.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this if you want the whole list somewhere all at once.  Assuming you're working on a tab called Sheet1 and that the word 'Activity' is in A2 as in your screenshot:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A100,SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(Sheet1!B2:100="x",Sheet1!B2:2,)),,9^9))," ")},"select Col1,Col2 label Col2'Week'",1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this formula, which is primarily built around `MATCH()`.

`=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("x", 3:3, 0), 4), "1", "")&"2")`